# Word search in Java

Tags: java, arrays, wordsearch

I am making a simple word search game in java. The code for finding horizontally works fine up to a point, like when searching for two letter words or some other words. It will print that the word is found twice, the first result is correct while the second onward is incorrect. The code below is for the search function of my program. I think the problem is occuring in the if statement bellow the findRight method call.

```
// to check if each row contains the user imputed word
public void search(String inWord){
    //loop through the arrays row length
    for(int i = 0; i < wordPuzzle.length; i++) {
        // loop through the column length in terms of array length
        for(int j = 0; j < wordPuzzle[i].length; j++) {
            if (wordPuzzle[i][j] == inWord.charAt(0)) {
                findRight(wordPuzzle[i]);
                    if(findRight(wordPuzzle[i])){
                        System.out.println(word+" found horizontally at row "+i+" and column "+j+"!");
                    }
                findDown();
                    //if(findRight(wordPuzzle[i])){
                    //    System.out.println(word+" found vertically at row "+i+" and column "+j+"!");
                    //}
                findDiagonal();
                    //if(){
                    //    System.out.println(word+" found diagonally at row "+i+" and column "+j+"!");
                    //}
                // needs to print if the word has been found in the directions
            }
        }
    }
}

public boolean findRight(char[] inArray) {
    String row = new String(inArray);
    boolean wordFlag = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
        if(row.contains(word)) {
           for(int j = 0; j < row.length(); j++){
               if(row.charAt(j) == (word.charAt(0))){
                  String subRow = new String(inArray, j, word.length());
                  if(subRow.contains(word)) {
                     wordFlag = true;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return wordFlag;
}
```

Comment: Where is `word` defined?

Comment: In some code above that I didn't include, but basically the code asks the user to input a word that they want to search for, then their input is stored in the word variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of word search on MxN board in Java. Words can be placed in any direction: Horizontally (from left to righ, from right to left), Vertically(from top to bottom, from bottom to top), Diagonally (any direction).

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

/**
 * Created on 1/21/17.
 */
public class WordSearchPuzzle {

    private int currentChar; // Index of current character searched in word array
    private char word[]; //Searched word

    public boolean wordExists(char board[][], String word) {

        if (word.isEmpty()) {
            throw new InputMismatchException("Searched word can not be empty!");
        }
        this.word = new char[word.length()];
        currentChar = 0;

        for (int a = 0; a < word.length(); a++) {
            word.getChars(0, word.length(), this.word, 0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                if (this.word.length != 0 && board[i][j] == this.word[currentChar]) {
                    if (this.word.length == 1) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (letterExists(board, i, j, this.word[++currentChar], "N")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    currentChar = 0;
                    if (letterExists(board, i, j, this.word[++currentChar], "NE")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    currentChar = 0;
                    if (letterExists(board, i, j, this.word[++currentChar], "E")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    currentChar = 0;
                    if (letterExists(board, i, j, this.word[++currentChar], "SE")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    currentChar = 0;
                    if (letterExists(board, i, j, this.word[++currentChar], "S")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    currentChar = 0;
                    if (letterExists(board, i, j, this.word[++currentChar], "SW")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    currentChar = 0;
                    if (letterExists(board, i, j, this.word[++currentChar], "W")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    currentChar = 0;
                    if (letterExists(board, i, j, this.word[++currentChar], "NW")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    //otherwise continue to search from first letter of given word,
                    //starting with some another position in the board
                    currentChar = 0;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean letterExists(char board[][], int i, int j, char letter, String direction) {

        if (i < 0 || i > board.length || j < 0 || j > board.length) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Unable to search for letter " + letter + " with coordinates (" + i + ", " + j + ")");
        }

        currentChar++;//advance search character to next letter in word

        if (i - 1 >= 0 && board[i - 1][j] == letter && direction.equals("N")) { //search N
            if (currentChar == word.length)
                return true;
            return letterExists(board, i - 1, j, word[currentChar], "N");
        } else if (i - 1 >= 0 && j + 1 < board[i].length && board[i - 1][j + 1] == letter && direction.equals("NE")) {//search NE
            if (currentChar == word.length)
                return true;
            return letterExists(board, i - 1, j + 1, word[currentChar], "NE");
        } else if (j + 1 < board[i].length && board[i][j + 1] == letter && direction.equals("E")) { //search E
            if (currentChar == word.length)
                return true;
            return letterExists(board, i, j + 1, word[currentChar], "E");
        } else if (i + 1 < board.length && j + 1 < board[i + 1].length && board[i + 1][j + 1] == letter && direction.equals("SE")) { //search SE
            if (currentChar == word.length)
                return true;
            return letterExists(board, i + 1, j + 1, word[currentChar], "SE");
        } else if (i + 1 < board.length && board[i + 1][j] == letter && direction.equals("S")) {//search S
            if (currentChar == word.length)
                return true;
            return letterExists(board, i + 1, j, word[currentChar], "S");
        } else if (i + 1 < board.length && j - 1 >= 0 && board[i + 1][j - 1] == letter && direction.equals("SW")) { //search SW
            if (currentChar == word.length)
                return true;
            return letterExists(board, i + 1, j - 1, word[currentChar], "SW");
        } else if (j - 1 >= 0 && board[i][j - 1] == letter && direction.equals("W")) { //search W
            if (currentChar == word.length)
                return true;
            return letterExists(board, i, j - 1, word[currentChar], "W");
        } else if (j - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 >= 0 && board[i - 1][j - 1] == letter && direction.equals("NW")) { //search NW
            if (currentChar == word.length)
                return true;
            return letterExists(board, i - 1, j - 1, word[currentChar], "NW");
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char row1[] = {'a', 'm', 'e', 'r' };
        char row2[] = {'m', 'i', 'z', 'g' };
        char row3[] = {'k', 'l', 'b', 'f' };
        char row4[] = {'s', 't', 'o', 'c' };
        char row5[] = {'b', 'a', 'y', 'a' };

        char board[][] = new char[5][4];
        board[0] = row1;
        board[1] = row2;
        board[2] = row3;
        board[3] = row4;
        board[4] = row5;

        WordSearchPuzzle puzzle = new WordSearchPuzzle();
        if (puzzle.wordExists(board, "ezb")) {
            System.out.println("Word exists!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Word doesn't exist!");
        }
    }
}
```